# Is there a way to show a form after clicked the first submit on first form?

Tags: php, jquery, html

is possible to show the 2nd form? after clicked the 1st form submit button? and is there a way to hide the second form?

**example**

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit']))
  { #show form 2 
  } 

  ?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

if theres a way to hide form 2

```
<form action="" method="post" name="form2">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

thanks in advance fellow web developers

Comment: Yes, you can. PseudoCode: `on(firstform submit) { if valid => show second form}`

Comment: Yes to both questions. Assign different names to each submit button and make the appropriate logical test for each name individually

Comment: im new on php. can you guys at least give me a hint of codes? it will be much appreciated

Comment: @JustAngelo Check my answer for your solution.

Comment: @JustAngelo Let me know if it helps...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Move the condition down.

```php
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

But note that, you have the same `name` in both the `form`'s submit button, so it is better to disable the previous `form`'s submit:

```php
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
  <input type="submit" name="submit"<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { echo ' disabled="disabled"'; } ?>>
</form>
<?php if (isset($_POST['submit'])) { ?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form2">
  <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: The condition will Always be `true` for both forms. Why?

Comment: @Tushar Kindly check... `:)`

Comment: ll change those names, its just for the example. btw this is great, thank you so much!